# USB issues and problem with Hauppauge WinTV Nova-T 500

Tags: usb

I'm using a Gigabyte GA-B75M-D3H motherboard for a mythtv box which I've recently upgraded from an M2NPV-VM motherboard where I've never had an issue.

My problem is that no USB devices will work from power-up until approx 60 seconds after boot. The USB mouse and keyboard both work immediately at power up and in the BIOS, but then stop working as soon as GRUB starts up. This is more of an inconvenience but I've never seen USB devices not work for a period of time and then start working later.

Since the capture card I use is a Hauppauge WinTV Nova-T 500 PCI card which has a built-in USB 2.0 hub and 2x USB 2.0 tuners in this also doesn't work. Unlike the mouse/keyboard which start working after 60 seconds, this capture card never works.

I think the problem is the USB 2.0 hub on the Hauppauge card is being incorrectly identified as a USB 1.1 hub, dmesg shows :

```
[   55.181377] usb 4-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[   55.319431] usb 4-1: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[   55.359740] dib0700: loaded with support for 21 different device-types
[   55.361404] dvb-usb: found a 'Hauppauge Nova-T 500 Dual DVB-T' in cold state, will try to load a firmware
[   55.363511] dvb-usb: downloading firmware from file 'dvb-usb-dib0700-1.20.fw'
[   56.972099] dib0700: firmware started successfully.
[   57.474026] dvb-usb: found a 'Hauppauge Nova-T 500 Dual DVB-T' in warm state.
[   57.474102] dvb-usb: This USB2.0 device cannot be run on a USB1.1 port. (it lacks a hardware PID filter)
[   57.474119] dvb-usb: Hauppauge Nova-T 500 Dual DVB-T error while loading driver (-19)
[   57.474138] usbcore: registered new interface driver dvb_usb_dib0700
```

Under dmesg, all message look fine up until 17 seconds in where there is a large delay of about 37 seconds related to USB issues.

```
[   17.686253] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 2, error -110
[   17.798232] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
[   33.350555] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 3, error -110
[   33.462532] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[   43.892050] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 4, error -110
[   44.004038] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[   54.433546] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 5, error -110
[   54.433557] hub 3-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[   54.517607] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
[   54.610615] hub 1-1.3:1.0: USB hub found
[   54.610699] hub 1-1.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[   54.681724] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
```

I've had this capture card working fine with previous versions of ubuntu and other motherboards, but I suspect the issue is USB related.

lsusb shows the capture card as :

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 2040:9950 Hauppauge WinTV Nova-T-500
```

uname -a shows the kernel as :

```
3.2.0-24-generic-pae
```

I am using an Intel Core i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz

Ubuntu version 12.04 LTS with all updates applied.

I've tried changing several BIOS options related to USB and looked into ACPI type issues and tried ACPI kernel options but have come up blank, it seems nothing I change makes a difference.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I don't think the Hauppage device is the hub referred to. Unless you have an external hub, the message is talking about one of the hubs implemented on the chip set on the motherboard. They are present on all systems with USB ports. Have you tried moving the device from one USB port to the others? One of my computers had USB ports that couldn't be run as 2.0 devices. Another had lot's of errors on one of the USB ports (fixed with a new motherboard but moving my Hauppage to a different port circumvented the problem).

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this issue, the Gigabyte GA-B75M-D3H needed a BIOS upgrade to version F15 to make it work.

John S Gruber - this most definitely is a PCI device with a USB hub which reports having 2 DVB-T tuners attaced

http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Hauppauge_WinTV-NOVA-T-500

```
03:02.2 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. USB 2.0 (rev 63)
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2040:9950 Hauppauge WinTV Nova-T-500

[    4.480190] dvb-usb: found a 'Hauppauge Nova-T 500 Dual DVB-T' in cold state, will try to load a firmware
[    4.493134] dvb-usb: downloading firmware from file 'dvb-usb-dib0700-1.20.fw'
[    5.277272] dvb-usb: found a 'Hauppauge Nova-T 500 Dual DVB-T' in warm state.
[    5.277541] dvb-usb: will pass the complete MPEG2 transport stream to the software demuxer.
[    5.871841] dvb-usb: will pass the complete MPEG2 transport stream to the software demuxer.
[    6.489185] dvb-usb: schedule remote query interval to 50 msecs.
[    6.489189] dvb-usb: Hauppauge Nova-T 500 Dual DVB-T successfully initialized and connected.
[    6.489307] usbcore: registered new interface driver dvb_usb_dib0700
```